# Dip to pixel conversion results in the exact same value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert dips to pixels using the following function.  I’ve tried low, medium, and high density emulators and regardless of the emulator I use, the pixel value remains the same value as the dip value I pass into the function.

```
private int ConvertDips(float dips) {
 int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) dips, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
 return pixels;
}
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my own fault.  The emulator was basically lying to the system and telling my app it was resolution x-y.  All part of what it was supposed to do according to the Android support screens documentation.  I needed to properly set up resources within the correct folders so that it would no longer lie to my application.

Comment: could you please make the answer clear. I am facing the same problem. What do you mean by "setting the resources within correct folder" ?