# Converting dip to pixels yielding the same value

Tags: android, pixel, density-independent-pixel

I need to convert density independent pixels to pixels in my activity.
I tried using this method in my onCreate

```
float pix = dipValue * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
pixel = Math.round(pix);
```

I tried another method

```
Resources r = getResources();
float pix = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35,r.getDisplayMetrics());
value = Math.round(pix);
```

both are yielding the same value. I think the problem is not with the method but with the resources. Should I make any changes in the Manifest file like

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037114/dip-to-pixel-conversion-results-in-the-exact-same-value) to mine. But it is not solving my problem. Help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert dip to px in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399184/convert-dip-to-px-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a
>   160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system
>   for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently
>   handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual
>   density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen
>   pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi
>   screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp
>   units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of
>   your UI on screens with different densities.

Please check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the dp value in dimen.xml and use

`int pixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.idDimension);`

It's easier...